# Cardinality of equivalence classes modulo a relation defined using two subgroups

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $H,K$ be two subgroups of a group $(G,\cdot)$.
We consider the relation $\sim$ defined on $G$ by :
\begin{equation}
x \sim y \iff  \exists (h,k) \in H \times K, \; y=hxk
\end{equation}
It's easy to verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G$.
We are told to show that, if $H$ and $K$ are finite, then every equivalence class modulo $\sim$ is finite and its cardinality divides $|H||K|$.

For that we are told to consider, f
or all $x$ in $G$:

\begin{equation}
G_x=\{ (h,k) \in H \times K \; : \; hxk^{-1}=x \}
\end{equation}

which is a subgroup of the product group $H \times K$.
From this, I can see that we'll have to relate the cardinality of $G_x$ and the equivalence class of $x$ and use Lagrange's theorem. However I don't see how to make that connection.

Comment: You could try searching for "double cosets"

Comment: About the finiteness, it suffices to note that $[x]_\sim=\{hxk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$, whence $\operatorname{card}([x]_\sim)\le |H||K|$.

Answer (score 1):

About the finiteness, it would suffice to note that, by definition, $[x]_\sim=\{hxk∣h∈H,k∈K\}$, whence ${\rm{card}}([x]_\sim)≤|H||K|$, due to the possible repetitions of the product $hxk$ in the RHS.

To get more insight, note that $(h,k)\cdot x:=hxk^{-1}$ is an action of $H\times K$ on $G$; in fact, $\forall x\in G$ and $\forall (h,k),(h',k')\in H\times K$:
$$(e,e)\cdot x = exe^{-1}=exe=xe=x$$
and
\begin{alignat}{1}
(h,k)\cdot((h',k')\cdot x) &= (h,k)\cdot h'xk'^{-1} \\
&= h(h'xk'^{-1})k^{-1} \\
&=(hh')x(k'^{-1}k^{-1}) \\
&=(hh')x(kk')^{-1} \\
&=(hh',kk')\cdot x \\
&=((h,k)(h',k'))\cdot x \\
\end{alignat}
With this at hand, you can recognize that $[x]_\sim$ and $G_x$ are respectively the orbit and the stabilizer of $x\in G$ for this action, and the claim follows then from the orbit-stabilizer theorem.